# search bar searching for Product Name in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am just trying to get Product Name in results.aspx  from the database through the search bar but I only get the products by their corespondant numbers.

Here is the code that works:

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProduct([QueryString("srch")] int? ProductId)
{
    var _db = new project.Models.ProductContext();
    IQueryable<Product> query = _db.Products;
    if (ProductId.HasValue && ProductId > 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.ProductID == ProductId);
    }
    else
    {
        query = null;
    }
    return query;
}
```

But when I want to the search results through product Name I face an issue. The code That does not work is:

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProduct([QueryString("srch")] int? ProductName)
{
    var _db = new project.Models.ProductContext();
    IQueryable<Product> query = _db.Products;
    if (ProductName.HasValue && ProductName > 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.ProductName= "srch");
    }
    else
    {
        query = null;
    }
    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to search by product name but your assigned data type is int. You are also missing an `=` on your syntax which will cause build errors.

```
    public IQueryable<Product> GetProduct([QueryString("srch")] string ProductName)
    {
        var _db = new project.Models.ProductContext();
        IQueryable<Product> query = _db.Products;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductName))
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.ProductName == ProductName);
        }
        else
        {
            query = null;
        }

        return query;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error as well as logical Errors in the given code, You did the search query with integer value, a simple comparison with that code will help you to realize what's wrong.

You should use `==` for comparison, Hope that you know about the `=`, it is used in c# to assign a value. Your code will always compare the product name with `"srch"` since you are comparing the value with the string `"srch"`, instead for that you should use the parameter that is passed to the function. Then one more thing you need to change the type of the argument. Its still int, you should make it as string(assume that `ProductName` will be a string) So your query will be Like this:

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProduct([QueryString("srch")] string ProductName)
{
     var _db = new project.Models.ProductContext();
     IQueryable<Product> query = _db.Products;
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductName))
     {
         query = query.Where(p => p.ProductName == ProductName);
     }
     else
     {
         query = null;
     }
     return query;
}
```